# Slicing Output Files

Tags: python, numpy, scientific-computing

I'm reading in a large file and I want to write a certain portion of it to a new file.

The pattern 'CARTESIAN COORDINATES' appears twice in this file and I want to omit everything before the second occurrence in the new file. So far I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import string,sys
import numpy as np
from numpy import *

with open("101.out", "r") as f:
    content = []
    for line in f:
        content.append(line)

g = open('101.xyz', 'w')


#write the relevant stuff


f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm assuming the `101.out` file looks something like:

```
not to be written 
not to be written
CARTESIAN COORDINATES
not to be written
CARTESIAN COORDINATES
written 
written
written
```

And you want all the stuff after the second `CARTESIAN COORDINATES` if I've understood you correctly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import string,sys
import numpy as np
from numpy import *

with open("101.out", "r") as f:
    content = []
    occurances = 0
    for line in f:
        if occurances >= 2: 
            content.append(line)
        if 'CARTESIAN COORDINATES' in line:
            occurances += 1

with open('101.xyz', 'w') as f:
    for item in content:
        f.write(item)
```

None of those imports are required for the work, I've just left them there because they were in your original snippet.

This outputs to `101.xyz`:

```
written
written
written
```